# "Activation of network connection failed" ubuntu 23.3 HP Pavilion 15 11 gen

Tags: drivers, wireless

`Activation of network connection failed` Ubuntu 23.3 Ubuntu version 23.3 on HP Pavilion 15 laptop
The problem: connected wifi after 10 Mint disconnected and is not showing any wifi, network wifi is unavailable

```
$ sudo apt install inxi
inxi -F
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
inxi is already the newest version (3.3.29-1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
System:
  Host: manish Kernel: 6.5.0-9-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME
    v: 45.0 Distro: Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eh2xxx v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8A0E v: 16.50 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: F.07 date: 07/04/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 22.6 Wh (59.8%) condition: 37.8/37.8 Wh (100.0%)
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5625U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP cache: L2: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2681 min/max: 400/4388 cores: 1: 1914 2: 2819 3: 3037
    4: 2983 5: 2395 6: 2609 7: 2223 8: 3015 9: 2988 10: 3258 11: 1915 12: 3019
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Barcelo driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-2: Quanta HP Wide Vision HD Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.23.2 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.0
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3 renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics
    (renoir LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.54 6.5.0-9-generic)
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-9-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.79 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek driver: rtw89_8852be
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: 10:6f:d9:e7:b5:25
  Device-2: ICS Advent DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter driver: dm9601 type: USB
  IF: enx00e04c534458 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 00:e0:4c:53:44:58
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 10:6F:D9:E7:B5:26 bt-v: 5.3
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 23.01 GiB (4.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN530
    SDBPNPZ-512G-1006 size: 476.94 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.35 GiB used: 23 GiB (4.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 1.05 GiB used: 6.1 MiB (0.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 4 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swap.img
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 63.9 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 50.0 C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): fan-1: 0 fan-2: 0
Info:
  Processes: 395 Uptime: 1m Memory: total: 8 GiB note: est. available: 7.1 GiB
  used: 2.85 GiB (40.2%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.29
```

Comment: Please clarify your OS/release details; you mention Ubuntu 23.3, but there was no release in 2023-March, are you using Ubuntu? if so which product & release (Server? Desktop? but made a typo?), or are you using another OS?

Comment: Please attach more system info: `sudo apt install inxi` and then `inxi -Fxxzc0` in terminal

Comment: which details explain

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu version 23.3

laptop using hp pavlion 15

The problem facing: connected wifi after 10 mint disconnected and not showing any wifi  network wifi unavailable

```
sudo apt install inxi
inxi -F
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
inxi is already the newest version (3.3.29-1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
System:
  Host: manish Kernel: 6.5.0-9-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME
    v: 45.0 Distro: Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eh2xxx v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8A0E v: 16.50 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: F.07 date: 07/04/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 22.6 Wh (59.8%) condition: 37.8/37.8 Wh (100.0%)
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5625U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP cache: L2: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2681 min/max: 400/4388 cores: 1: 1914 2: 2819 3: 3037
    4: 2983 5: 2395 6: 2609 7: 2223 8: 3015 9: 2988 10: 3258 11: 1915 12: 3019
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Barcelo driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-2: Quanta HP Wide Vision HD Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.23.2 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.0
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3 renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics
    (renoir LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.54 6.5.0-9-generic)
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-9-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.79 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek driver: rtw89_8852be
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: 10:6f:d9:e7:b5:25
  Device-2: ICS Advent DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter driver: dm9601 type: USB
  IF: enx00e04c534458 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: 00:e0:4c:53:44:58
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: 10:6F:D9:E7:B5:26 bt-v: 5.3
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 23.01 GiB (4.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN530
    SDBPNPZ-512G-1006 size: 476.94 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.35 GiB used: 23 GiB (4.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 1.05 GiB used: 6.1 MiB (0.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 4 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swap.img
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 63.9 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 50.0 C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): fan-1: 0 fan-2: 0
Info:
  Processes: 395 Uptime: 1m Memory: total: 8 GiB note: est. available: 7.1 GiB
  used: 2.85 GiB (40.2%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.29
```

Comment: Please edit your original post and include this text there